Is "Boy, I bet you're tired after that walk." an exclamatory sentence?
My son got this question wrong on his test and I have always been under the impression that an exclamatory sentence has an exclamation mark. Can someone please clarify?

Boy, I bet you're tired after that walk.

The teacher states this sentence is exclamatory.

Cross posted here... https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/27775/is-this-sentence-exclamatory

It is unclear what you are asking.  Should it have an exclamation mark or is it exclamatory?  What was the exact question ?

I’m asking if the sentence “Boy, I bet you’re tired after that walk.” Is an exclamatory sentence? Can an exclamatory sentence not have an exclamation mark. Teacher states that an exclamatory sentence DOES not always have an exclamation mark.

The teacher is correct. The exclamation mark indicates the tone only.

The answer is whatever your teacher tells them. Some sources say an exclamatory sentence must end in an exclamation mark; others that it's customary but not necessary. Modern grammar distinguishes structure and usage; the Oxford Dictionary of Grammar uses exclamative for structure (e.g. that of "How big he is!") and exclamation for usage, expressing emotion (although it acknowledges an exclamative is often called an exclamation). But elementary school teachers are unlikely to use modern grammatical categories, so it's hard to know what the teacher means without more information.

Without an exclamation point, we cannot tell. We would have to hear it.

You're wholly correct. In any relevant context, an exclamatory sentence by definition demands an exclamation mark. Your teacher is as welcome as Greybeard to explain how any exception could apply, without the support of missing context…

According to the authors of EnglishClub, an exclamatory sentence mandatorily ends with an exclamation mark:


Exclamative Sentence (exclamation): Exclamative sentences express strong emotion/surprise—an exclamation—and they always end with an
exclamation mark/point (!).


Whereas those of MasterClass reduce mandatorily to 'typically':


Exclamatory sentences: An exclamatory sentence, also known as an exclamation sentence or an exclamative clause, is a statement that
expresses strong emotion. Typically, in English grammar, exclamatory
sentences end with an exclamation mark—also called an exclamation
point.


Other sources can be found supporting both viewpoints. Study.com {courtesy of Google} chooses 'typically', while most other pundits opt for 'mandatorily'.
As even the word 'sentence' is given conflicting definitions (syntax- vs semantics-based), it is rather pointless arguing over whether one or the other school is correct. As usual, the best idea is to go with what your authority figure expects, have a discussion about their stance if they're reasonably disposed, and when you're out from under their authority choose a balanced view but be consistent in your usage.
Quirk et al in CoGEL when giving examples of the subset of interrogative-form exclamatory sentences (which the example here isn't a member of) display only sentences which do have an exclamation mark – to distinguish the stress pattern from the corresponding pure interrogative:

Were you hungry! [obviously a stressed rhetorical question] [stress on first two words]

contrast

Were you hungry? [when spoken, stress switches to the adjective]

FWIW, I'd use

"I bet you're tired after that walk." for a gentle expression of solicitousness.
"Wow/Boy, I bet you're tired after that walk!" for a more robust word of solicitousness.
"Wow/Boy! I bet you're tired after that walk!" for a really emphatic word of solicitousness.

And I'd regard all variants as involving exclamative sentences ('I bet' is a sufficient marker).

Quirk et al didn't write CaGEL!

I confess to blasphemy. But then CGEL (or its acolytes) even hijacked the initialism.

I'd wager you're dead tired probably isn't an exclamation. I agree--without the exclamation mark, I'm not sure it's a glatt kosher exclamation.

An exclamatory sentence is one that has exclamatory force. This could be marked by an exclamatory marker such as boy or wow or by the use of a special construction such as an exclamative clause, or one using subject-auxiliary inversion and so forth, or, very importantly even just by intonation.
The Original Poster asks whether exclamatory sentences always have exclamation marks. What they want to know is whether a sentence they have seen can be an exclamatory sentence when it didn't have an exclamation mark.
So do all exclamatory sentences have an exclamation mark? The answer is an emphatic 'No!'. This can be easily proved merely by observing that most exclamatory sentences are spoken and not written.
Do all written examples of exclamatory sentences have exclamation marks? The answer is 'no'. An exclamatory sentence is one where the speaker conveys that some aspect of the sentence should be understood to be extremely highly relevant. An exclamation mark is just an orthographical device for helping a writer to show that a sentence should be understood to be said with exclamatory intonation, or with exclamatory force. There are no hard and fast rules about how this should be achieved or punctuated, or even for being able to tell decisively that a particular sentence is exclamatory - especially when written.
However, there do exist 'exclamatory markers', words that speakers use specifically to convey that a sentence should be understood to be exclamatory. Unlike punctuation, these are part of the actual language. One of these is the item 'boy' (not the noun, the other one). The occurrence of this item in OP's son's example is sufficient for him to label it exclamatory sentence.

An exclamation mark is punctuation, and punctuation is merely a feature of the textual representation of the utterance. The phrasing of the utterance is far more dispositive than punctuation, and  Boy at the start of an utterance is clearly an exclamation marker in speech.
Teachers would do well to distinguish between the language per se and its representation on the page. There are all sorts of language features not represented well, or at all, by punctuation and by text.

In fact this sentence could be   written as follows so as to make evident that it is exclamatory.

Boy! I bet you're tired after that walk.

"Boy" is an interjection, as "man" is also, in American English. (Origin of "man!", "(oh) boy!", and "oh brother" , OLD)
It seems that for very short sentences the exclamation point can be put at the end, but there should be an exclamation point somewhere.
An exclamation point should be used at the end of a strong command, an interjection, or an emphatic declaration. (Ginger)

The word boy normally comes within the same intonational phrase (IP) as the rest of the sentence, and therefore doesn't need to be set off as a separate sentence. This is easily demonstrated by the fact that the word boy can come after a coordinator like the word and before the rest of the sentence: "... , and boy I needed it!"

@Araucaria-Him In "and boy I needed it!" it seems right to use no exclamation mark, I agree, but this is not true in all contexts. For instance, here is a case of use of the exclamation mark ("Boy! What a day!").

@Yes, it could be two sentences. If iut represents two IPs. But there's nothing to say it would be more proper as two sentences!

'Boy…' is no 'interjection…' It's an address; a polite equivalent of 'Hey, You!'
Either way, 'Boy…' and 'man' are equally deserving of capitals… will you choose both, or neither?
As Posted, 'Boy, I bet you're tired after that walk' could as easily be a query, or an error. Neither context nor your punctuation gives any clue…
